# How to stop all JS scripts in Puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I would like to be able to stop any scripts from being able to run in puppeteer after the page has loaded. The reason for this is to stop carousel images and lazy loading images and essentially get the page to behave as statically as possible to enable screenshots where the images aren't changing etc.

By doing `page.evaluate('debugger;')` it is possible to pause the whole script, but this does not let you continue with taking screen shots as the a `evaluate` function does not exit until you exit the debugger (If the gui is enabled)

Comment: remove `script` tags after load?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After phoning a friend the following seems to work:

```
await page.evaluate('document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 10):

```
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)
```

[`Page.setJavaScriptEnabled` docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setjavascriptenabled)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to disable JavaScript after the page has loaded, you can use [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger):

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  debugger;
});
```

**I was able to take screenshots after using the debugger.**

Alternatively, you can replace each original node with its clone to remove the events attached to each element:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(element => {
    element.parentNode.replaceChild(element.cloneNode(true), element);
  });
});
```

You can also use [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) in a loop similar to the one above to remove specific events attached to a node.

Otherwise, if you can disable JavaScript before the page has loaded, you can use [`page.setJavaScriptEnabled()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetjavascriptenabledenabled) before navigating to the page:

```
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you have to close the debugger to take the screenshot? For me the script pauses when the deugger is open and nothing else will run till I close it. As soon as I close the debugger the js starts running again.

Answer (score 5):

A better solution is just to block all requests with the type equals to `script`:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on("request", request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === "script") {
      request.abort()
    } else {
      request.continue()
    }
  })

  await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/")
  await browser.close()
})()
```

Source: [Disabling JavaScript Using Puppeteer](https://webkul.com/blog/disabling-javascript-using-puppeteer/)

Comment: Would still evaluate / run inline scripts

Comment: This does not work as we still need the scripts to load all the images initially and then stop them from running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to freeze the page and still be able to call `evaluate` on it, you can

1. navigate to the page, wait for it to load (and maybe let its JavaScript make some DOM transformations),
2. get HTML snapshot of the page,
3. disable JavaScript,
4. reload the page statically (no DOM transformations will occur since JavaScript is disabled),
5. profit (do any amount of `evaluate` or screenshots on a DOM that is guaranteed to stay the same).

```js
await page.goto('<url>', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); // 1
const html = await page.content(); // 2
page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false); // 3
await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); // 4
```